# is there a way to see what work was committed to a certain commit in a branch?

Tags: git, commit

I did some work on a branch a long time ago, now I need to make some changes but dont remember what I did. How do I find out what files/changes were committed given the commit code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git show <sha1>
```

Where

```
<sha1>
```

is your "commit code"

Answer (score 1):

`git whatchanged -1 -p <sha>` is one way. `git log -1 -p <sha>` is similar.